# Shiny Ratings Input

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to follow a code to build a recommender system. One of the steps asking that I call for `library(ShinyRatingInput)`. I attempted to install the package but I received below error:
`Warning in install.packages: package ‘ShinyRatingInput’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)`

Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you for any guidance that can be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the code you used for install this package?

Since this package is not available on CRAN, so you can not use `install.packages` function

You have to use

```
devtools::install_github("stefanwilhelm/ShinyRatingInput")
```